# Redirect non-matching routes in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am looking for equivalent of `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` in Angular 2.

**More details:**

I have a router definition like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: "/", component: MultiPost, name: "Home", useAsDefault: true },
  { path: "/m/:collectionName/:categoryName/:page", component: MultiPost, name: "MultiPost" }
])
```

Both routes are working perfectly, for instance when I hit `/` or `/m/sth/sth/0` I got what I want.

But when I hit a random url like `/kdfsgdshdjf` nothing happens. Page is rendered and `<router-outlet>` is empty since no route is matched.

What I want to do is to redirect all non matching routes to a default one. I need something like `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");`.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature hasn't been implemented yet:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2965

Comment: Bad news for me, but thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Yea, I'm looking forward for this too, you can still redirect with the backend server though.

Comment: It is now implemented and could be used like this:
const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ];

Answer (score 6):

There is no 'otherwise' route in angular 2 yet. But the same functionality can be achieved using wildcard parameter, like so:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', redirectTo: ['Home'] },
    { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
    // all other routes and finally at the last add
    {path: '/*path', component: NotFound}
```

This will only load the 'NotFound' component and the url will be same as what you navigate to. In case you want all not matching routes to redirect to a '404' url, you can do something like:

```
//at the end of the route definitions
{ path: '/404', name: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
{ path: '/*path', redirectTo:['404'] }
```

Comment: @Langley answer was correct though this should be accepted as this provides the solution also.